# Prolog Empty list within lists

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog and an exercise in a course says to erase every atomic element in a list, that may be an overlapping list.
If I have

```
clean([1,[2,[3],4],5],L).
```

It should become

```
L = [[[]]]
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to think through each case of a list that you might encounter.  For example, if you encounter an empty list, then what is the answer?  The answer is simply the empty list.

```
clean([],[]).
```

Now, what if the first element is an atom (not another list)?  Then we remove the element -- which means we don't add it to the result list.

```
clean([H|T],L):- \+ is_list(H), clean(T,L).
```

And finally, what if the first element is another list?  Then we add the list to the answer, but only after cleaning it.  The way to add it to the answer list, is by "pre-pending" it as the head of the answer list, so "[Empty|L]".

```
clean([H|T],[Empty|L]):- is_list(H), clean(H,Empty), clean(T,L).
```

Put the above clauses together in a program and that's your answer.